# Generic '90s / early '00s sci-fi movie series with a reference to Tom & Jerry cartoons having been banned

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

I'm looking for a sci-fi series, set in space, where I have one scene in my mind:

The spaceship captain is doing his PhD-or-similar in history, namely about late 20th/early 21st century and we hear him putting onto the audio-log that "just after Tom & Jerry has been banned because of being too brutal". Meanwhile a husband-and-wife crew member pair is exploring possibilities for certain adult acts in 0g. This second one is happening on a spherical observation station (mostly glass) on the side of the spaceship.

It may well be an episode and side-story of [Mercy Point](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164097/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), I definitely have seen it in TV around the same time of airing of that one. I'm, however, unsure about whether it's Mercy Point and cannot seem to find any episodes of that show available so that I could verify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is *[Supernova](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134983/)* (2000).

It does feature a captain working on his PhD, and a reference to old cartoons like Tom & Jerry having been banned due to the level of violence.

From [a review](https://vocal.media/geeks/the-2000s-movie-project-review-supernova):

> Supernova stars James Spader as Nick Van Zant, a military man in some future time who has been sent to work in an emergency medical vehicle in space. Robert Forster plays the captain, Markley who we meet, oddly, as he is working on a dissertation on violence through the lens of Tom & Jerry cartoons. **His voiceover indicates that Tom & Jerry had been banned hundreds of years earlier.** This plays no role in the rest of this movie.

Apparently there was also a low gravity sex scene, originally shot with Robin Tunney and Peter Facinelli, and later altered with CGI to make it look like the lovers were the characters played by James Spader and Angela Bassett.

From [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_(2000_film)):

> When he took over the editing of the film, Francis Ford Coppola put together the zero-gravity sex scene between Angela Bassett and James Spader using outtakes of the zero gravity sex scene between Robin Tunney and Peter Facinelli that happens later in the film, with Tunney's skin color being digitally darkened. He did this to add more to the relationship between Bassett's and Spader's characters.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Supernova mentions the ban.

Comment: *David* Spader?

Comment: Ah, so it wasn't a series but a movie! Thanks for the answer (and the welcome touch-up edits on my question).